# Dynamically Changing text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script which calls and displays the users phone number to them on a header.  That works great.  However, I am needing to change text on the page that I can't edit directly.  There is a phone number that I am needing to replace with the same ID as the header.

Help me change the href 800 number and the span 800 number with jQuery please!  I'm stuck!

The code below is hard coded and I don't have access to change it.  So it must be done dynamically.

```
<div class="flex-item flex-item-nogrow navbar-icon" id="navbarPhoneNumber">
                <a href="tel:8005555555" class="flex-wrapper align-items-center navbar-icon-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>(800) 555-5555</span>                </a>
            </div>
```

I have tried this

```
$("#navbarPhoneNumber a").html("<i class='fa fa-phone' aria-hidden='true'></i><span id='phonenumber'></span>");
```

It didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to change it to? Have you tried something already? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to change it using the same element ID that displays the top bar in red.  Doesn't work though...

Comment: I am wanting to change the 800 number with the phone number called from the geolocation script I am using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#navbarPhoneNumber a").replaceWith("<i class='fa fa-phone' aria-hidden='true'></i><span id='phonenumber'></span>");
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

```
var $phoneNumberA = jQuery('#navbarPhoneNumber a');
var $phoneNumber = jQuery('#navbarPhoneNumber span');

$phoneNumberA.attr('href', $phoneNumberA.attr('href').replace(/(tel:...)/, 'tel:123'));
$phoneNumber.text($phoneNumber.text().replace(/\(.*\)/, '123'));
```

Comment: [Code-only answers are strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69683045/edit) to explain how/why the code solves the problem. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30153134)